# Batch does not compute equations properly

Tags: batch-file

I recently tried to write a program in batch that calculates square root of any real number (instead of negative numbers) without using external commands or tools and the program is based on the algorithm that can be found here: [Link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm)

**EDIT:** Most of the problem I fixed, but there is still a slight undetected by me problem.

Please run this 'debug mode' code: [Link2](http://pastebin.com/Rd8HGYKV) and test the output for number 15625 and precision 3.

In order for the code to be correct, the debug code has to display:

```
- finalpart: 1
2
adder: 56
- finalpart: 44
3
adder: 25
- finalpart: 1225
4
adder: 0
Answer: 125
```

Comment: Yeah I meant 32-bit limit, I just rushed over writing this post. Thanks for correction

Comment: I'd maybe check this out [Batch square root calculator](http://batchprogrammers.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-calculate-sqrt-of-number-in.html), I'm terrible at math, but looking at that should get you in the right direction.

Comment: I already did the whole logic and it should work. I just need help in getting the syntax right because batch instead of calculating properly, gives zero for every answer, even though variables have non-zero value and should give non-zero answer.

Comment: Change `%answer%` to `!answer!` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: No. It still gives 0.0000 as answer. It is something in the fragment I posted up in my original post.

Comment: @TrupKrupDróbGrób You can do this: `if %%p leq !nowcut! set operation=!cut%%p!` but you CANNOT do this: `if !pplus! leq !nowcut! set "adder=!cut%pplus%!"`  You are inside a code block and you can't use a pseudo array like that.  The token %%p is already expanded, but %pplus% is still equal to the previous time it was set even though you added one to it.

Comment: @TrupKrupDróbGrób Any time you manipulate a variable inside parentheses and need to use that variable again, you need to reference it with delayed expansion. But in this case you can't do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TrupKrupDróbGrób and here is an instance where you are using Delayed Expansion but do not even need to use it: `if %multip%==1 set/a cut!nowcut!="cut!nowcut!*10"`

Comment: @TrupKrupDróbGrób, try this instead. `if !pplus! leq !nowcut! CALL set "adder=%%cut!pplus!%%"` and remember to change all of your other variables to use delayed expansion when you are inside parentheses.

Comment: @TrupKrupDróbGrób, I tried to fix all the syntax errors you have with your code but I still cannot get it to give me the correct answer for simple square roots like 9 and 16.  What you may want to do is turn ECHO ON and put some pauses in your code and watch it execute.  This way you can see what values the variables are all expanding to. That way you could step through an odd number like 11 and if you know what the logic is supposed to do then you should see the variables expand to what you know they should be.  Then you will know it is either a logic flaw or syntax problem.

Comment: It worked! The program almost works, I just need to fix small thing.

Comment: Try this code! It works for most square roots, there is just one thing messed up I have to fix for it to fully work. Try doing for example 625, 64, 9, 0.25. It works for those. wait...

Comment: This is the link: http://pastebin.com/jsBWA53y

Comment: @TrupKrupDróbGrób, I can't get to the code as my Company blocks a lot of file sharing sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me. If you want that we review your code looking for errors I can not help you. Your code is large and have not a single descriptive comment, and several variable names are confusing and prone to cause editing errors. I reviewed your link to the Wikipedia article and the method seemed interesting to me, but when I compared the described method with your program the code seemed unnecessarily complex, so I decided to write my own version of that method; I apologize if this is not what you asked for.

In this program the precision is set to the number of decimals / 2 of the input number, but a very simple modification would allow to set it to a fixed number. I tested this program with multiple numbers and works correctly.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:nextNumber
   set "number="
   set /P "number=Number:      "
   if not defined number goto :EOF
   call :SquareRoot %number% sqrt=
   echo Square root: %sqrt%
   echo/
goto nextNumber


:SquareRoot number result=
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Separate the number in aligned blocks of 2 digits each
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ("%1") do set "int=%%a" & set "frac=%%b"
set /A i=11, f=10
:nextInt
   if not defined int goto nextFrac
   set /A i-=1
   set "block[%i%]=%int:~-2%"
   set "int=%int:~0,-2%"
goto nextInt
:nextFrac
   if not defined frac goto checkLastBlock
   set /A f+=1
   set "block[%f%]=%frac:~0,2%"
   set "frac=%frac:~2%"
goto nextFrac
:checkLastBlock
if %f% gtr 10 if "!block[%f%]:~1!" equ "" set "block[%f%]=!block[%f%]!0"

rem Get square root of first block: digit between 0 and 9
set /A num=block[%i%], iP1=i+1, addZeros=0
for /L %%r in (0,1,9) do (
   set /A r2=%%r*%%r
   if !r2! leq %num% set /A sqrt=%%r, remainder=num-r2
)

rem Get square root of next blocks
for /L %%i in (%iP1%,1,%f%) do (
   set /A remainder1=remainder*10+!block[%%i]:~0,1!, remainder2=remainder*100+1!block[%%i]!-100, sqrtT2=sqrt*2
   if !sqrtT2! equ 0 (
      rem The number started with zeros: no sqrt yet
      set "sqrt="
      set /A addZeros+=1
      for /L %%r in (0,1,9) do (
         set /A r2=%%r*%%r
         if !r2! leq !remainder2! set /A nextDigit=%%r, remainder=remainder2-r2
      )
   ) else if !remainder1! lss !sqrtT2! (
      rem There is no sqrt for this block
      set /A nextDigit=0, remainder=remainder2
   ) else (
      set /A nextDigit=remainder1/sqrtT2, test=sqrtT2*10+nextDigit, this=test*nextDigit
      if !this! gtr !remainder2! (
         rem Next digit is too large: decrease it
         set /A "times=(this-remainder2)/test+1"
         for /L %%t in (1,1,!times!) do if !this! gtr !remainder2! (
            set /A nextDigit-=1, test=sqrtT2*10+nextDigit, this=test*nextDigit
         )
      )
      set /A remainder=remainder2-this
   )
   set "sqrt=!sqrt!!nextDigit!"
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%addZeros%) do set "sqrt=0!sqrt!"
set /A point=11-i
set "sqrt=!sqrt:~0,%point%!.!sqrt:~%point%!"
endlocal & set "%2=%sqrt%"
exit /B
```

Output example:

```
Number:      15625.000000
Square root: 125.000

Number:      625
Square root: 25.

Number:      64
Square root: 8.

Number:      9
Square root: 3.

Number:      0.25
Square root: 0.5

Number:      987654321987654321
Square root: 993807990.

Number:      1234567890123456789
Square root: 1111111106.

Number:      2.000000000000000000
Square root: 1.414213562
```

Comment: No, I didn't want you to fix the logic behind my code, I just had a syntax problem that I could not fix, and I could locate it. You see, I'm kind of new in programming, so I am not good in putting algorithms into best code. But thanks for helping, I will analyze your code to see what you did. +1

EDIT: There is just one slight bug in your code that when you put for example 2.(fifty zeros) then answer is kind of deformed: "1.4142135620000-6689126400-105277030400000000" But still it works better than mine.

Comment: Time for trying to do trigonometric functions in pure batch ;)

Comment: Like this one? Sine: `for /L %%x in (0,5,90) do (` & `set /A "a=%%x*31416/180, sin=a-a*a/1920*a/312500+a*a/1920*a/15625*a/15625*a/2560000-a*a/1875*a/15360*a/15625*a/15625*a/16000*a/44800000"` & `set sin=000!sin!` & `echo %%x - 0.!sin:~-4! )`

Answer (score 1):

This code shows 30 decimal of the square root.

here is My Way :

```
@echo off
title SQR
set /p x=PLS Enter Your Number = 
echo.
echo Wscript.Echo (FormatNumber(SQR(Wscript.Arguments(0)),30))>Q.vbs
cscript //nologo Q.vbs %x% & DEL "Q.vbs"
PAUSE>NUL
```